# wrong integer number of label after deleting row

Tags: swift, uitableview

I Have some little problem. My UiTable has a custom cell. every cell include a Label with number of row. when I open app and press button "Add", for example 4 times - new rows have been inserted(1, 2, 3, 4) When I delete row number 2, i have a result (1,3,4). What can I do with my label to reorder integer value of row number, because after deleting row 2 I want to see row numbers 1, 2 , 3 (not 1, 3, 4). Thanks!

Comment: This depends on your data model and source. Basically you have to reload the cells from the changed row to the end.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "every cell include a Label with number of row." Are you installing text into your labels that contains the 1-based row number?

If that's the case you'll have to use UITableView.reloadData() to reload all the cells, since normally the data displayed for a cell does not depend on it's position in the table view.

(Or at least reload all the cells from the changed row to the end, as vadian suggests in his comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Call this function whenever you add or delete a row in table view

```
func updateCellsNumber() {
        let totalCell = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
        for row in 0..<totalCell {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            cell.numberLabel.text = "row+1"
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile. It's very inefficient anyway because it's going to update also cells which are not visible at the moment.